# Wordpress: website base url appended to URLs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog powered by Wordpress 4.2.10 hosted on my website. In Google's Search Console, I get a lot of 404s that are all following this pattern:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/an-article-url/www.mywebsite.com
```

Search Console tells me that these URLs are indexed on these:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/an-article-url/
```

But I can't find the wrong URL anywhere on these pages.

My guess is that I have a plugin that is doing this but I looked at all the settings of all my plugins without any luck. Here are all the active plugins:

- Add Widget After Content
- Akismet
- Enable Media Replace
- Fancier Author Box
- Google Analytics by Yoast
- ImageRecycle pdf & image compression
- jQuery Colorbox
- Knight Lab TimelineJS
- Recent Posts Widget Extended
- SlideShare
- SSH SFTP Updater Support
- Widget Logic
- WordPress File Monitor Plus
- WP-reCAPTCHA
- Yoast SEO

So my question is: how do I get rid of these URLs that do not exist?

Comment: right click >view source > Ctrl + f (search) and see where they are in the source code. That should give you some clue whats doing it. Probably some canonical url meta tag. As a blind guess, i would look at Yoast as a first step

Comment: I actually did that (that's what I meant with "I can't find the wrong URL anywhere on these pages") but these URLs are not in the source code. Thanks I'll try to look at the Yoast plugin.